# Как отформатировать JSON для вывода?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, форматирование

Хотел бы узнать, есть ли какой-нибудь способ отформатировать вывод JSON, чтобы он был более читабельный? Как например, на <del>[этом веб-сайте](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)</del>.

Для XML использую:

```
var rc refcursor
declare
    xml varchar2 (128) := '<contacts><contact><name>aaa</name><phone>123/456789-0</phone></contact></contacts>';
    pretty clob;
begin
    select 
        xmlSerialize (Document xmlType (xml) indent size = 2) pretty into pretty 
    from dual;
    open :rc for select pretty pretty from dual;
end;
/

PRETTY
--------------------------------
<contacts>
  <contact>
    <name>aaa</name>
    <phone>123/456789-0</phone>
  </contact>
</contacts>
```

И это работает прекрасно.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to pretty format JSON in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54864047) от участника [@Iván](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7567648/iv%c3%a1n)</sub>

Comment: ассоциасция:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54864047

Answer (score 4):

Начиная с версии 12c можно воспользоваться функцией [`JSON_QUERY()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/function-JSON_QUERY.html#GUID-D64C7BE9-335D-449C-916D-1123539BF1FB) с клаузой `RETURNING ... PRETTY`.

> **PRETTY**
> Specify PRETTY to pretty-print the return character string by inserting newline characters and indenting.

Пример синтаксиса:

```
JSON_QUERY(js_value, '$' RETURNING VARCHAR2(4000) PRETTY)
```

Воспроизводимый пример ([на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ac66e36ef96a93e3d8acf844535b1520)):

```
with t as (
    select '{"a":1, "b": [{"b1":2}, {"b2": "z"}]}' js from dual
)
select json_query (js, '$' returning varchar2 (4000) pretty) prettyjson, js 
from t;
```

Вывод:

```
PRETTYJSON                       JS                                   
-------------------------------- -------------------------------------
{                                {"a":1, "b": [{"b1":2}, {"b2": "z"}]}
  "a" : 1,                                                            
  "b" :                                                               
  [                                                                   
    {                                                                 
      "b1" : 2                                                        
    },                                                                
    {                                                                 
      "b2" : "z"                                                      
    }                                                                 
  ]                                                                   
}
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54866009) от участника [@GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Если установленна 19c, есть еще один вариант для форматирования вывода [JSON_SERIALIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_SERIALIZE.html).

Эта функция позволит преобразовывать между `VARCHAR2,CLOB,BLOB`, и имеет опцию `PRETTY`:

```
with t as (
    select '{"a":1, "b": [{"b1":2}, {"b2": "z"}]}' js
    from dual
) select json_serialize (js returning varchar2 pretty) prettyjs, js
from t
/
PRETTYJS                         JS                                   
-------------------------------- -------------------------------------
{                                {"a":1, "b": [{"b1":2}, {"b2": "z"}]}
  "a" : 1,                                                            
  "b" :                                                               
  [                                                                   
    {                                                                 
      "b1" : 2                                                        
    },                                                                
    {                                                                 
      "b2" : "z"                                                      
    }                                                                 
  ]                                                                   
}
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54867633) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>